# req.body.name is undefined

Tags: node.js, html

Hello i have a form that i am sending to the server but when it reaches the handler. I try to print out the contents but the body is undefined. Please could someone what i did wrong.

```
<form action="/myactive" method="POST">
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"> Male<br>
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Medium</button>
</form>
```

and below my server side is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3030);

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Index page');
});

app.post('/myaction', function(req, res){
    console.log('Name: '+req.body.name); //returns undefined
    res.end("Welcome");
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Listening on port '+app.get('port'));
});
```

But on the console it prints

```
Name is undefined.
```

Comment: Is `req.body.name`  undefined or `req.body`? because in your code example you write `console.log('Name: '+req.body);`

Comment: @t.niese i attempted both but returned undefined req.body.name

Comment: req.body returns an array with objects

Comment: @t.niese req.body.name returns undefined

Comment: Your inputs are named `gender` and `female`. On the one hand `female` should be named `gender`, and there is not input with the name `name`, so you need to add an input with the name `name`.

Comment: @t.niese thanks for the correction. But now when i do req.body it returns `[object, Object]` but i want it to returns the actual value

Comment: `name="gender"` => `req.body.gender`,  `name="name"` => `req.body.name`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the same `action` in your form  with the post route that you have in the server. So `/myactive -> /myaction`. Moreover there is no `name` property in the `req.body` object. When you specify `name="gender"` in your form it means that the `gender` property will be attached to the `req.body` object

```
<form action="/myaction" method="POST">
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"> Male<br>
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female  
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Medium</button>
</form>
```

And you can retrieve the selected gender from your route using below code

```
app.post("/myaction", function(request, response) {
    console.log("Gender is:", request.body.gender);
    response.sendStatus(200)
});
```

Comment: when attempt to print req.body it returns `[object, Object]` how i can print the actual contents

Comment: @user3497437 Use `JSON.stringify(request.body)`

Comment: @user3497437 If you want to print the actual contents of the object, just either console.log it alone: `console.log(req.body);` or use a comma instead of string concatenation: `console.log('Body:', req.body);`

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any input with `name="name"`,

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"> Male<br> 
<input type="radio" name="female" value="Female"> Female
```

you can get either `req.body.gender` or `req.body.female`.

To get the right value, do this:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"> Male<br> 
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female
```

then you can get the value with `req.body.gender`

Comment: when attempt to print req.body it returns [object, Object] how i can print the actual contents

Comment: @user3497437 did you add `app.use(bodyparser.json());` as @vkstack mentioned?

Comment: @user3497437 you can't get actual value with `req.body`, you need to get them with `req.body.gender`

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead `console.log('Name: '+req.body.gender);`

Comment: `req.params` is for the parameter within the path (`/user/:id`).

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you use **req.body** make sure to use `body-parser` to parse the content in the body...

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

> you should define the above in the same order as above.

your data is in `req.body.gender`