# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. I cannot find the reason why I get this error. I am using mysql, nodejs and ejs as view engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am Trying to Add new users into a MySql database in nodejs and EJS as a view engine. I do get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined error. Can somebody please assist as I cannot find the reason why I get this error.

```js
My Routing

const express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const mysql = require("mysql");
const mysqlConnection = require("../connection");

router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  let mysql = "SELECT * FROM user_index.clients";
  let query = mysqlConnection.query(mysql, function (err, rows) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      res.render("users", {
        title: "Mysql with EJS",
        users: rows,
      });
    }
  });
});

router.get("/add", function (req, res) {
  // res.send("My add page.");
  res.render("add", {
    title: "Mysql with EJS",
  });
});

router.post("/add", (req, res) => {
  let data = {
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
  };
  let mysql = "INSERT INTO clients SET ?";
  let query = mysqlConnection.query(mysql, data, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please provide full text of the error message, including filename, line and column -- as reported by Node.js.

Comment: I have tried to copy and paste that but get a warning that the message is to long. I also wanted to add my app.js file for reference but it seems that stackoverflow does not want me to add more code. All works well on the landing page so I am sure that body-parser is set up correctly.

Comment: The Second line gives me this:at C:\Users\polok\Desktop\Javascript Projects\Backend\MYSQL EJS\routes\people.js:29:20

Comment: I believe it's just you don't have a name property sended via post request you made from your frontend. Can you try to debug `req.body` and see if there is a `name` prop there

Comment: <div class="container">
      <h1><%- title %></h1>
      <form action="/add" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="name"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Enter Name"
            required
          />
        </div>

Comment: you can debug your code,by removing parts of your code one by one.Once you removed a part, the error disappeared, you know where the bug is located at. And I also think it's `req.body` being undefined that cause the error. Put a `console.log(req.body)` and check.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809724/req-body-name-is-undefined/36809947#36809947

Answer (score 1):

Since you're submitting a `html-form` you need a corresponding [parser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#bodyparserurlencodedoptions) in order to be able to access the submitted data under `req.body`. Adding the following middleware before your handlers should fix the problem:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
...
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```